# How to convert the testing RevMobAds into production

Tags: ios, revmobads

I m using `RevMobAds` first time in my app using this code:

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@" "];
[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
[[RevMobAds session]hideBanner];

RevMobBannerView  ad = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView];

ad.delegate = self;
[ad loadAd];
ad.frame=CGRectMake(00, 430, 320, 50);

[self.view addSubview:ad];`
```

The problem is this no add is showing in the banner.Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Please try like this :

**Step:1** Add RevMovAds.framework.

**Step:2** In `AppDelegate` Method import `#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>`

**Step:3** Add `Delegate` Method `"RevMobAdsDelegate"`

**Step:4** Define  `#define REVMOB_ID @"52f073fa09e95bbb02000761"` in Prefix.pch

(Create a account on RevMobAds site & get REVMOB_ID for your Application)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:REVMOB_ID];
  return YES;
}
```

**Step:5** Declare the method

```
-(void)ForshowingFullScreenAds
{
   RevMobFullscreen *fullscreen = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
   fullscreen.delegate = self;
   [fullscreen loadAd];
   [fullscreen showAd];
}
```

**Step:6** `RevMobAdsDelegate` methods

```
- (void)revmobAdDidReceive 
{
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] Ad loaded.");
}

- (void)revmobAdDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] Ad failed: %@", error);
}

- (void)revmobAdDisplayed {
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] Ad displayed.");
}

- (void)revmobUserClosedTheAd {
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] User clicked in the close button.");
}

- (void)revmobUserClickedInTheAd {
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] User clicked in the Ad.");
}

- (void)installDidReceive {
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] Install did receive.");
}

- (void)installDidFail {
   NSLog(@"[RevMob Sample App] Install did fail.");
}
```

**Step:7** Import `AppDelegate` Method

**Step:8** Call this Ads in `-(void)ViewDidLoad`

```
  AppController *App = (AppController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [App ForshowingFullScreenAds];
```

Comment: Thank you  sir,i have completed.

Comment: i don"t use your code .i remove this line  [RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;   and then it work fine on device.